# Reusing snowflake connection object in multiple python scripts

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, code-reuse

I'm using
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(user='user',password=password,account='account',warehouse='warehouse',database='db')

for the snowflake connection in every single python script to execute sql query. Instead I need to create this object once and reuse this in all my python scripts. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked into just running your python scripts as Snowflake procedures, instead?  Snowflake runs python natively...no connections needed.